# Using Reflection to create extensible charts for a website

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I’m trying to implement a website where new charts can be added by just dropping a DLL into folder. At the time of writing it is not clear what charts are going to be needed and this provides a simple way of deploying new charts without having to redeploy the website in its entirety. I’m using Google Charts to provide the Google functionality and each chart will be displayed
Each type of chart inherits from the following Interface
public enum ChartType
{
BAR,
COLUMN,
PIE,
TABLE
}

```
public class DataColumn 
{
    public String ColumnType { get; set; }
    public String ColumnValue { get; set; }

}

public interface IChart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary of Columns, Each column is defined as a type and title
    /// </summary>
    List<DataColumn> Columns { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ChartType, What type of Chart; possible values BAR, COLUMN, PIE, TABLE
    /// </summary>
    ChartType ChartType { get;  }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data - data for the chart
    /// </summary>
    String Data { get;  }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the chart, must be unique used to identify each chart stub
    /// </summary>
    String Name { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Title - the title that will be displayed above the chart
    /// </summary>
    String Title { get;  }

    /// <summary>
    /// What position will the legend of there is one.
    /// </summary>
    String LegendPosition { get;  }

}
```

The following uses the above interface

```
public class ReferralDownloadCount : IChart, IDisposable
{
    List<ChartDemo.DataColumn> columns = null;

    public ReferralDownloadCount()
    {

        columns = new List<ChartDemo.DataColumn>()
        {
            new ChartDemo.DataColumn() { ColumnType = "String" , ColumnValue = "Date" },
            new ChartDemo.DataColumn() { ColumnType = "Number" , ColumnValue = "Referral Count"}
        };

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the chart data
    /// </summary>
    public String Data 
    { 
        get 
        {
            String sql                      = String.Empty;
            String jsonResult               = String.Empty;
            DataSet ds                      = null;
            DataTable dt                    = null;
            List<ReferralCountData> results = null;
            JsonSerializer serializer       = null;

            try
            {
                sql = "Select * From[Portal].[ReferralCount] Where DATEDIFF(d, [Download Date], Convert(Date, GETDATE())) < 8 Order By[Download Date] Asc";
                ds  = DataToolbox.Execute(new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnection), sql, CommandType.Text);

                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    dt      = ds.Tables[0];                      // we really are only expecting one table
                    results = new List<ReferralCountData>();

                    serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());

                    foreach ( DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        using (ReferralCountData rcd = new ReferralCountData()
                        {
                            Label = ((System.DateTime)dr.ItemArray[0]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                            Value = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Referral Count"])
                        })
                        {
                            results.Add(rcd);
                        }
                    }

                    jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);


                }
            }
            catch ( System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {

            }

            return jsonResult;
        } 
    } 

    public List<ChartDemo.DataColumn> Columns {
        get
        {
            return columns; 
        }
        set
        {
            columns = value;
        } 
    }

    public ChartType ChartType => ChartType.COLUMN;

    public string Name => "REFERRALCOUNT";

    public string Title => "Referral Download Count"; 

    public string LegendPosition => "None"; 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The site traverses a directory containing DLLs, and searches for any classes such as the one above to create Charts
Classes which have inherited from IChart are then extracted as each DLL is checked by GetChartPlugins

```
static List<IChart> GetChartPlugins(List<Assembly> assemblies)
{

    List<Type> availableTypes = new List<Type>();
    List<Type> alertList = null;

    try
    {

        foreach (Assembly currentAssembly in assemblies)
            availableTypes.AddRange(currentAssembly.GetTypes());


        alertList = availableTypes.FindAll(delegate (Type t)
        {
            List<Type> interfaceTypes = new List<Type>(t.GetInterfaces());

            return interfaceTypes.Contains(typeof(IChart));
        });

    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Exception exSub in ex.LoaderExceptions)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(exSub.Message);
            FileNotFoundException exFileNotFound = exSub as FileNotFoundException;
            if (exFileNotFound != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exFileNotFound.FusionLog))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("Fusion Log:");
                    sb.AppendLine(exFileNotFound.FusionLog);
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        string errorMessage = sb.ToString();
    }
    catch ( System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    // convert the list of Objects to an instantiated list of ICalculators
    return alertList.ConvertAll<IChart>(delegate (Type t) { return Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IChart; });
}
```

However when this runs the attempt to Call currentAssembly.GetTypes() falls over throwing a ReflectionTypeLoadException
Which eventually becomes;

Method 'get_Columns' in type 'ReferralManagementCharts.ReferralDownloadCount' from assembly 'ReferralManagementCharts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
Can anyone see why since the Columns property of ReferralDownlodCount

```
    public List<ChartDemo.DataColumn> Columns {
        get
        {
            return columns; 
        }
        set
        {
            columns = value;
        } 
    }
```

Does have a get.

Comment: I bet that `DataColumn` is not `ChartDemo.DataColumn` or not from the same library ... you should move interface into another assembly and add reference into main project and plugin to the same library

Comment: I would like to see the implementator of IChart in plugin.dll